# Как использовать многочлены Чебышева для работы со списком?

Tags: python, list, numpy, список, анализ-данных

Как использовать полиномы Чебышева для работы со списком?

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y = [10,20,30,4,10,10,20,2,2,20]
```

```
from numpy.polynomial.chebyshev import Chebyshev

for i in [4]:
    c = Chebyshev.fit(x, y, i)
    c(x)
```

Но как их сделать в рамках списка?

Код выше не работает, по каким причинам не знаю.

Comment: что значит `"сделать в рамках списка"` ?

Comment: Сейчас это работает только в рамках df, а со списками не работает

Comment: `c = Chebyshev.fit(x, y, i)` - тоже замечательно работает...

Comment: Да как то не очень...

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (__«почему этот код не работает?»__) должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения __прямо в вопросе__. Вопросы без __явного описания проблемы__ бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. как создать [mcve].

Comment: исправил вопрос

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Судя по ошибке:

```
In [21]: c(x)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-497ccf32130c> in <module>
----> 1 c(x)
...
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64'
```

метод [Chebyshev(x)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.chebyshev.Chebyshev.fit.html#numpy.polynomial.chebyshev.Chebyshev.fit) ожидает `numpy.ndarray` или `Pandas.Series` в качестве параметра `x`:

```
In [22]: c(np.array(x))
Out[22]:
array([18.10909091, 16.12121212, 14.43636364, 13.05454545, 11.97575758,
       11.2       , 10.72727273, 10.55757576, 10.69090909, 11.12727273])
```